# How many distinct values can be used while running scorecard for a column?Table contains 40million records,almost 100k distinct values in column

Tags: informatica

How many distinct values can be used while running scorecard for a column? Because my table contain 40million records and there are almost 100k distinct values in column. After executing score card I can see results are incorrect. Please help me

I was trying to come to know this in many ways but did not get the answer.

Comment: what are you actually trying to achiever here? are you trying to rank the records or do a distinct of the column.

Comment: I have house number column. Almost 100k distinct values in that column. I have edited score card and chosen valid and invalid values before running scorecard. It seems there is limitation that Informatica Analyst can have maximum 16000 values including valid and invalid section and uses these values to run scorecard but my table conatin 40 million records. I want to execute scorecrd using 100k distinct values in house number column. Is it possible by any way? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Within the Administration Console > Data Integration Service > Properties > Advanced Profiling Properties, you will see the 'Maximum # Value Frequency Pairs' is set by default to 16000.  You can change this (and then **restart the DIS**) to a higher number if you feel like you need to see more values.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to implement this and will let you know,.

Comment: One more input for me : After executing profiling It provides 4 results for us like values,patterns,datatypes,statistics. When it comes to values it is showing only 200 entries with data in the column and frequency of data in the column. Is there any way we get all distinct values along with their frequencies from a column. As I told you in my scenario table contains 40million records and in column 100k. distinct values are there. As you suggested for score card, do we have any setting for this?

Comment: are you getting 200 values form the api? If yes, then you need to iterate the results to get the complete list.

Comment: Yes, in the right pane. In the drop down we have values,patterns,datatypes,statistics right. When I chose values i can see only 200 entries.

Comment: Do we have any setting to change in the server level to get all the Distinct values along with frequencies. I think by default it it showing only 200 entries. Please help.

Comment: i think you are in enterprise edition, which allows you to fetch only 200. If you are in performance edition you can get 2000 and thats the maximum. IMO, You have to iterate to get all the values. i dont think any  option like you are expecting does NOT EXIST.

Comment: try this video: https://network.informatica.com/videos/2655 . this should help you to get started with pagination.

Comment: I need one more help. This one I got new requirement : Is it possible to connect from Informatica developer to SAS database?
I have to do profiling and scorecards on SAS tables..
Can I access SAS database through Informatica developer. I need to do data quality activities on SAS database.

Comment: If you feel this answer helped, then accept this as the right answer. So in future, if anyone has the same question, they can refer to this easily. You need to use power exchange to connect to SAS database. once you connect the rest of the data quality checks are standard for the tool.

Comment: https://kb.informatica.com/proddocs/Product%20Documentation/6/PWX_102_SASUserGuideForPowerCenter_en.pdf

Comment: Thanks Sir for your response. Now it is confirmed we can not connect from IDQ to SAS. We need to use power exchange to connect to SAS. We are planning to dump data from SAS database to Oracle database instead of using power exchange, Thanks a lot for your respones.

Comment: One question : You said using informatica power exchange we can connect to SAS and import tables. But how can I use tables which are imported in power exchange but it is not in to Informatica developer right. Please help me to let me know.

Comment: Multiple ways to do that. My personal favorite would be to import into power center and then go to developer, import metadata from power exchange metadata repository. This is how I used to do

Comment: Ok. I don't know as we can import table structures from power exchange to developer or  power center to developer. What about connection to SAS to execute any stuff  in informatica developer.

Comment: i am not longer getting the context of your question. Please create a new question, if this is no longer realted to increasing the limit and accept the answer. Thanks